# normal elements in spectral theory.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, c-star-algebras

If $x$ is a normal element in a $C^{*}-algebra$ then $x$ is unitary $\iff$ $\sigma(x) \subseteq (the \ unit \ circle \ in \ the \ complex \ plane)$. According to the book I am reading this should be "obvious" according to continuous functional calculus. I somehow understand the proof of this direction $\implies$. However, is it possible to show the other direction without using functional calculus, the direction where we assume $\sigma(x) \subseteq (the \ unit \ circle \ in \ the \ complex \ plane)$ and then show it forces $x$ to be unitary?

Comment: Formatting tip: Don't use math mode for emphasis – it looks terrible! Instead, *put the text between asterisks for italics*, **between double asterisks for bold**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me start by saying that I see absolutely no reason of avoiding the functional calculus. Trust me: it is your best friend in a $C^*$-algebra. However, here is an argument.

I will use that the spectrum in a unital abelian $C^*$-algebra described as

$$\sigma(x)=\{\phi(x):\phi:A\to\mathbb{C}\text{ is a nonzero *-hom}\}$$

and that, if $B\subset A$ is a unital inclusion between $C^*$-algebras, then $\sigma_B(b)=\sigma_A(b)$ for all $b\in B$ (something more general is true, but this suffices for our purposes). You can find these facts in any elementary operator algebras textbook, such as Murphy.

Let $A$ be a unital $C^*$-algebra and let $a\in A$ be a normal element with $\sigma(a)\subset\mathbb{T}$.

Now let $z\in\sigma(a^*a)$. Since $a$ is normal, $C^*(a,1_A)$ is a unital abelian $C^*$-algebra, unitally included in $A$. Also, $a^*a\in C^*(a,1_A)$. By the fact that $\sigma_A(a^*a)=\sigma_{C^*(a,1_A)}(a^*a)$ and the description of the spectrum in a unital, abelian $C^*$-algebra, namely in $C^*(a,1_A)$, we find a $*$-homomorphism $\phi:C^*(a,1_A)\to\mathbb{C}$ so that $\phi(a^*a)=z$. But then $z=\phi(a^*)\phi(a)=\overline{\phi(a)}\phi(a)=|\phi(a)|^2$. But again by our description and the invariance of spectrum in unital subalgebras we have $\phi(a)\in\sigma_{C^*(a,1_A)}(a)=\sigma_A(a)\subset\mathbb{T}$, so $|\phi(a)|^2=1$ and thus $z=1$. We have thus shown that $\sigma_A(a^*a)\subset\{1\}$ and we know that the spectrum is non-empty in Banach algebras, so $\sigma_A(a^*a)=\{1\}$. But this means $a^*a=1_A$, showing that $a$ is a unitary.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I can see that I should probably start trying to understand the Gelfand transform and map and then apply the functional calculus. It seems that one can show the iff statement in one go by applying those tools. What I have managed to come up with so far is that if                                                    $a$ is normal $\implies$ identify $C^{*}(a) \cong C(\sigma(a))$, with $\sigma(a): a(z) = z$. and notice that in $C(\sigma(a))$ the spectrum of a function $f$ is the image of $f$.. Btw. what do you mean by this notation: $C^{*}(a, 1_{A})$

Comment: @Chengdu $C^*(a,1_A)$ is the least $C^*$-subalgbera of $A$ containing $a,1_A$, i.e. the $C^*$-subalgebra generated by $a,1_A$. Since $a$ is normal, this is abelian.

Comment: you say that: "and the description of the spectrum in a unital, abelian $C^{*}$-algebra namely $C^{*}(a, 1_{A})$ we find a *-homomorphism. Is this a theorem, or just follows straight from the definition?

Comment: @Chengdu It follows form what I explicitly said I am going to use. This is a description of the spectrum of an element in a unital abelian $C^*$-algebra. I assume that you have already seen this, since you have learned about continuous functional calculus, I'd recommend going through your notes again

Comment: I have looked in my lecture notes and book, and I haven't been able to find that description of the spectrum of an element in a unital abelian $C^{*}$ algebra. The closest I came is the following theorem: If $\mathcal{A}$ is a commutative, unital Banach Algebra then $\sigma(A) = \{ \phi(A) \ | \ \phi \in \ maximal \ ideal \ space \} \ \forall \ A \in \mathcal{A} $. What's more how do we know that A being normal forces $C^{*}(a,1_{A})$ to be abelian?

Comment: @Chengdu And what is the maximal ideal space in your notes? For the second part, think about it yourself. If $a$ and $a^*$ commute, then the $C^*$-algebra generated by this is abelian. Use the fact that polynomials in $a$ and $a^*$ are dense in this $C^*$-algebra

Comment: AHA I think I see it now. A linear map $\phi : \mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is called a character if $\phi(AB) = \phi(A) \phi(B)$, $\forall A,B \in \mathcal{A}$. and we define the maximal ideal space, say $\mathcal{M}_{A} = \{ \phi : \mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathbb{C} \ | \phi \ charachter \neq 0 \}$. I think that definition compared with the theorem of unital banach algebras, should give the same as your definition of spectrum for an element in an abelian unital C*-algebra?